# Package restore failed when I use a portable library

Tags: sqlite, nuget, win-universal-app, entity-framework-core

I am trying to install the nuget pacakge EntityFramwork.Sqlite in a portable library which targets are .net 4.6 and windows universal 10.0. If I do that, I get an error that says package restore failed.

If I create  project library that is for .net 4.6 then I can add the package and if I create a universal portable library only for windows 10 applications, I can add the package too.

So, if I can use the package in .net 4.6 projects and windows universal projects, why can I not use it in a portable library that targets this kind of projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF7 currently targets `netstandard1.3` (aka `dotnet5.4`) and .NET 4.5.1. As of today (Jan 14, 2016), there is no PCL profile to includes both of these. (see http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY).

See also https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md